# Will the man in the relativistic train stop counting instantly?

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

Consider if you wave at a person in a relativistic train for 3s. Since they're traveling 0.86c they will see you wave for 6s.

However, from your frame of reference you see their timer as slow. As such, after you wave for 3 seconds, you see that their clock has only ticked 1.5s (I'm making these numbers up but I'm pretty sure their relative values should be correct).

Now that you stop waving, will they see that you stop waving when you stop waving or will they think you're still waving after you've stopped waving? (ignoring the time taken for the light to go from your hand to their face)

As in, if I could "instantly" communicate (I know it's impossible, but it makes this question easier to frame), when I stop waving and I ask them "have I stopped waving?", will they also say "yes you have stopped waving"? If so, then from my perspective they should see my wave as lasting for only 1.5s whereas they actually measure it as 6s? Am I correct?

Comment: I'd recommend you draw this situation in two Minkowski diagrams- one from the perspective of each observer. Take your time and do everything properly to scale. Make sure you draw the line corresponding to "instant communication" and that it is the same line in both diagrams.

Comment: @Chris I'd like to, but I'm not terribly well versed in them. I learnt this at high school and I'm still pretty much at that level (I'm at uni but not studying a math/phys major)

Answer (score 1):

If you wave at them for 3s as measured on your watch, during that time they will have travelled about half a million miles. They will not see you waving.

As a general guide, you are unlikely to find sensible answers to questions about relativity if you begin by ignoring the time taken by light to travel hundreds of thousands of kilometres.

To make your question less open to such criticisms, let us suppose that you and a friend are standing along a platform the train is passing. Each of you holds a nice large clock.

When the observer on the train passes you, he notes the time on your clock and you note the time on his. Three seconds later, in platform time, the observer on the train passes your friend, and notes the time on your friend's clock, while your friend notes the time on the observer's.

When you confer with your friend, your notes will show that the difference between the times you noted on the train clock was less than three seconds- that is, the train clock has been running slowly from your perspective.

The observer on the train will notice that the 3s difference in the readings on the two platform clocks is longer than the time that has passed on the train clock, and will conclude that the two platform clocks are out of synch.

Note that the arrangement I have described is not symmetrical, since you and your friend have noted the passage of time on a single clock on the train, whereas the observer on the train has noted the time on two different clocks on the platform. The observer on the train, therefore, sees a synchronisation effect, whereas you see a time dilation effect.

The arrangement can be made reciprocal by having a second observer on the train sitting some distance away from the first, so the two observers on the train can each make a note of your time as they pass you 3s apart in train time. When they compare their notes, they will see that their two readings of your clock will differ by less than 3s, so that your clock seems to be running slow. If you had made a note of the readings on both of the train clocks, you would conclude that they were out of synch with each other.

So, as a general principle, if two widely spaced observers make separate readings of a single clock moving between them, they will conclude the clock is running slow. If a single observer makes readings of two stationary clocks they are passing, they will conclude the clocks are out of synch.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't really well-posed, because the concept of "instantly communicating" is not Lorentz-invariant.

What does "instantly communicating" mean? The obvious definition is that if you send a signal at time $t_1=0$ from position $x_1=0$, it arrives at the destination $x_2 > 0$ at the same time $t_2=0$.

But now imagine this from the perspective of the other observer, who is traveling with $\gamma=2$. The Lorentz transform for time is given by $t^\prime=\gamma(t-\beta x)$. Applying this transform to both events gives $t_1^\prime=0$ and $t_2^\prime=-\beta\gamma x_2$.

From the perspective of the other observer, your "instantaneous" communication actually went backwards in time!

This is really just a statement that the simultaneity of two events is relative between two reference frames. If you try to insist on using the same concept of simultaneity with two different reference frames you'll run into weird, contradictory results.